# Meaning of "Preparation of x, y and z and ..."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have a question related to this example sentence:

> Preparation of Isometrics, bill of material of all lines and supporting details of all lines below 2-1/2" except lines under IBR and get subsequent approval.

From the above:

1. What are the sizes of lines for preparation of isometrics? Is it for all lines or for lines below 2-1/2"?
2. Is getting subsequent approval for (a) all isometrics, bill of materials and also for the supporting details or (b) only supporting details?

Comment: What is the context here?

Comment: This seems very unnatural to me as English.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very poorly worded sentence and the author should be asked for clarification before any further action was taken. If, however, I were forced to guess at the intended meaning this is how I would parse it:

> (a) Preparation of (a1) isometrics, (a2) bill of material of all lines and supporting details of all lines below 2-1/2" except lines under IBR and (b) get subsequent approval.

The long (a2) section is the primary source of confusion but I think it means to prepare the bill of material for all lines. And prepare supporting details of all lines that are both below 2-1/2" but are not under IBR.

The appropriate to say this in the future would be to include a list of all action items that need to be performed:

> Prepare the following:
>
> - isometrics
> - bill of material for all lines
> - supporting details for all lines below 2-1/2" except lines under IBR
>
> Also, get subsequent approval.